# ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm a newbie deploying my app on heroku, and as usual, it doesn't work at the first try. But in development environment, it works just fine. I don't understand quite well the logs, so if someone could be of help, it would be very appreciated. :-)

Here are my **logs** :

```rb
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:       <%= owned_products_count(@user) %>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/_info.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_users__info_html_erb___312310489209235041_69873501065000'
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2418451874712966399_69873501046980'
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ... "products" INNER JOIN "loans" ON "products"."id" = "loans"....
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <li id="borrowed_products_count">
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:       <b><%= t('product.borrowed.count', count: @user.borrowed_products.count) %></b>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "loans" ON "products"."id" = "loans"."product_id" WHERE "loans"."seeker_id" = $1 AND "loans"."current" = 't' AND "loans"."agreed" = 't'):
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     </li>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     </br>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.216823+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     </li>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <li id="wanted_products_count">
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/_info_products_count.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users__info_products_count_html_erb__2292303326639587721_69873501081120'
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ... "products" INNER JOIN "loans" ON "products"."id" = "loans"....
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     </li>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:       <%= owned_products_count(@user) %>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217058+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <li id="borrowed_products_count">
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:       <b><%= t('product.borrowed.count', count: @user.borrowed_products.count) %></b>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "loans" ON "products"."id" = "loans"."product_id" WHERE "loans"."seeker_id" = $1 AND "loans"."current" = 't' AND "loans"."agreed" = 't'):
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     </br>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217863+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2418451874712966399_69873501046980'
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217863+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217863+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/_info.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_users__info_html_erb___312310489209235041_69873501065000'
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217247+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     </li>
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217863+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/_info_products_count.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users__info_products_count_html_erb__2292303326639587721_69873501081120'
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217863+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <li id="wanted_products_count">
2013-07-04T04:52:28.217863+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-04T04:52:28.209972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/1 host=letroquet.herokuapp.com fwd="88.138.232.224" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=531ms status=500 bytes=1266
```

I understand there are some problems with the following files :

**app/views/users/show.html.erb**

```rb
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<aside class="span3">
  <%= render 'users/info' %>
</aside>
<section class="span9">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="dashboard_products">
    <li class="active"><a href="#sharable_products" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('tab.user.show.sharable')%></a></li> 
   <li><a href="#givable_products" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('tab.user.show.givable')%></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <%= render 'users/show/sharable_products_list' %>
    <%= render 'users/show/givable_products_list' %>
  </div>
</section>
```

**app/views/users/_info.html.erb**

```rb
<section>
  <div>
    <span class="gravatar">
      <a href="<%= user_path(@user) %>", title="<%= t('my.profile') %>"><%= gravatar_for @user, size: 52 %>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="name">
      <h1>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </span>
  </div>

  <%= render 'users/info_products_count' %>

    <%= link_to t('product.create.one'), new_product_path, class: "btn btn-primary" unless !current_user?(@user) %>
</section>
```

**app/views/users/_info_products_count.html.erb**

```rb
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li id="owned_products_count">
    <%= owned_products_count(@user) %>
  </li>
  <li id="borrowed_products_count">
    <b><%= t('product.borrowed.count', count: @user.borrowed_products.count) %></b>
  </li>
  </br>
  <li id="wanted_products_count">
    <%= wanted_products_count(@user) %>
  </li>
  <li id="requested_products_count">
    <%= requested_products_count(@user) %>
  </li>
  </br>
  <li id="given_products_count">
    <b><%= t('product.given.count', count: @user.given_products.count) %></b>
  </li>
  <li id="returned_products_count">
    <b><%= t('product.returned.count', count: @user.returned_products.count) %></b>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

And here my helpers methods for products :

```rb
module ProductsHelper
  def owned_products_count(user)
    content_tag(:b, t('product.owned.count', count: user.owned_products.count)) +
    content_tag(:ul,
    content_tag(:li, t('product.givable.count', count: user.givable_products.count)) +
    content_tag(:li, t('product.sharable.count', count: user.sharable_products.count))
    )
  end

  def wanted_products_count(user)
    content_tag(:b, t('product.wanted.count', count: user.wanted_products.count)) +
    content_tag(:ul,
    content_tag(:li, t('product.wanted.agreed.count', count: user.agreed_takings.count)) +
    content_tag(:li, t('product.wanted.refused.count', count: user.refused_takings.count))
    )
  end

  def requested_products_count(user)
    content_tag(:b, t('product.requested.count', count: user.requested_products.count)) +
    content_tag(:ul,
    content_tag(:li, t('product.requested.agreed.count', count: user.agreed_borrowings.count)) +
    content_tag(:li, t('product.requested.refused.count', count: user.refused_borrowings.count))
    )
  end
end
```

And there my **db/schema.rb**

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130621065539) do

  create_table "loans", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "product_id"
    t.string   "seeker_id"
    t.datetime "borrowing_date"
    t.datetime "return_date"
    t.boolean  "current"
    t.boolean  "agreed"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "loans", ["product_id", "seeker_id", "borrowing_date", "return_date", "current", "agreed", "created_at"], name: "loans_index"
  add_index "loans", ["product_id", "seeker_id", "created_at"], name: "index_loans_on_product_id_and_seeker_id_and_created_at", unique: true

  create_table "ownerships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "offerer_id"
    t.datetime "owning_date"
    t.datetime "giving_date"
    t.boolean  "current"
    t.boolean  "agreed"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "ownerships", ["product_id", "offerer_id", "created_at"], name: "index_ownerships_on_product_id_and_offerer_id_and_created_at", unique: true
  add_index "ownerships", ["product_id", "offerer_id", "owning_date", "giving_date", "current", "agreed", "created_at"], name: "ownerships_index"

  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "sharable"
    t.boolean  "givable"
    t.string   "picture_file_name"
    t.string   "picture_content_type"
    t.integer  "picture_file_size"
    t.datetime "picture_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token"

end
```

Comment: May be your field was defined as varchar.
Try to change it to be an integer.

Comment: What field are you referring to ?

Comment: i don't know your schema but going thru the error i can suggest that it might be product's id..can u share ur schema?

Comment: I edited my question to include it.

Comment: In ur loan schema u have product_id as string. change that to integer.

Comment: Ah ah ! It worked ! Excellent ! Thank you very much ! By the way, I don't know why I made string of id, but it was dumb ;-)
You can add your last comment as an answer if you want...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ur loan schema u have `product_id` as **string**. change that to **integer**.
Glad that it worked. :)

Comment: .. and here's how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537064/rails-migration-to-convert-string-to-integer